# Reduce an inequality

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I have this inequality I don't know why it is not working?!

```
Reduce[
  Sqrt[(-2/3 + γ)/((-2/3 + γ - Λ) a^2) + a^(-3 γ + 3 Λ) b] > 0 &&
    1 < γ < 2 && Λ > 0 && a > 0,
  b, Reals
]
```

Comment: Please paste Mathematica code that evaluates to something or is returned unevaluated without errors. Use `\[Gamma]` and `\[Lambda]` instead of what you are using currently. Thanks.

Comment: Bill it isn't working if I change the variables, Syed I just changed them.

Comment: As it is shown in my comments to my answer, I solved `Reduce[Sqrt[(-2/3 + \[Gamma])/a^2 + 
    a^(-3*\[Gamma] + 3*\[CapitalLambda])*(-2/
        3 + \[Gamma] - \[CapitalLambda])*b ]> 
   0 && -2/3 + \[Gamma] - \[CapitalLambda] > 0 && 
  1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && \[CapitalLambda] > 0 && a > 0, b, Reals]`

Answer (score 1):

A substitution and introducing an additional equation helps to find solutions.

```
f = Sqrt[(-2/
     3 + \[Gamma])/((-2/3 + \[Gamma] - \[CapitalLambda]) a^2) + 
 a^(-3 \[Gamma] + 3 \[CapitalLambda]) b] /. 
 Sqrt[aa__] -> Identity[aa] // Simplify

ruleee = ee -> 3 \[Gamma] - 3 \[CapitalLambda]

solee = First@
 Solve[3 \[Gamma] - 3 \[CapitalLambda] == ee, \[CapitalLambda]]

Maximize[{3 \[Gamma] - 3 \[CapitalLambda], 
   1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && \[CapitalLambda] > 
0}, {\[Gamma], \[CapitalLambda]}]

Minimize[{3 \[Gamma] - 3 \[CapitalLambda], 
  1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && \[CapitalLambda] > 
0}, {\[Gamma], \[CapitalLambda]}]

f2 = f /. solee
```

Solutions for different regions of b and ee.

```
red0 = Reduce[f2 > 0 && 1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && a > 0 && ee == 2, b]  (*  False  *)

red1 = Reduce[
f2 == ff2 && ff2 > 0 && 1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && a > 0 && b > 0 && 
2 < ee < 6, b];

rr1 = red1 /. ruleee // 
FullSimplify[#, 
 ff2 > 0 && 1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && a > 0 && b > 0 && 2 < ee < 6] &;

TraditionalForm[
rr1 //. Or -> 
Composition[(Column[#, Right, Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, 
   Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]

```
red2 = Reduce[
f2 == ff2 && ff2 > 0 && 1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && a > 0 && b > 0 && 
ee < 2, b];

rr2 = red2 /. ruleee // 
FullSimplify[#, 
 ff2 > 0 && 1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && a > 0 && b > 0 && ee < 2] &;

TraditionalForm[
rr2 //. Or -> 
Composition[(Column[#, Right, Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, 
   Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]

```
red3 = Reduce[
f2 == ff2 && ff2 > 0 && 1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && a > 0 && b < 0 && 
2 < ee < 6, b];

rr3 = red3 /. ruleee // 
FullSimplify[#, 
 ff2 > 0 && 1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && a > 0 && b < 0 && 2 < ee < 6] &;

TraditionalForm[
rr3 //. Or -> 
Composition[(Column[#, Right, Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, 
   Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]

```
red4 = Reduce[
f2 == ff2 && ff2 > 0 && 1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && a > 0 && b < 0 && 
ee < 2, b]

(*   False   *)
```

Comment: How do the above formulas describe a solution `{\[CapitalLambda] -> 46/169, \[Gamma] -> 43/34, a -> 1, b -> -(9/5)}` of the original system?This solution is obtained from mine  by `FindInstance[my solution,{\[CapitalLambda], \[Gamma], a, b}, Reals]`. TIA.

Comment: With the last line in rr3 `a == 1 && 2 < 3 \[Gamma] - 3 \[CapitalLambda] < 6 && 
  b + (2 - 3 \[Gamma])/(-(3 \[Gamma]) + 3 \[CapitalLambda] + 2) == 
   ff2 /. {\[CapitalLambda] -> 46/169, \[Gamma] -> 43/34, a -> 1, 
  b -> -(9/5)} `   yield `992/28085 == ff2 ` Condition ff2>0 is satisfied !

Comment: Can you elaborate your comment, giving us details? TIA.

Comment: Gave detailed description. Can't see anything unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Sqrt` over the reals takes only non-negative values, the system `Sqrt[(-2/3 + γ)/((-2/3 + γ - Λ) a^2) + a^(-3 γ + 3 Λ) b] > 0 && 1 < γ < 2 && Λ > 0 && a > 0` (which cannot be solved by `Reduce`) is equivalent to the system

```
(-2/3 + γ)/a^2 + 
   a^(-3*γ + 3*Λ)*(-2/
       3 + γ - Λ)*b > 
  0 && -2/3 + γ - Λ > 0 && 
 1 < γ < 2 && Λ > 0 && a > 0
```

Now:

```
Reduce[
  (-2/3 + γ)/a^2 + a^(-3*γ + 3*Λ)*(-2/ 3 + γ - Λ)*b > 0 &&
    -2/3 + γ - Λ > 0 && 
      1 < γ < 2 && Λ > 0 && a > 0,
  b, Reals
]
```

returns the following:

```
(a == 1 && 1 < γ < 2 && 
   0 < Λ < 
    1/3 (-2 + 3 γ)) || ((Log[a] | 
      E^(-((-2 + 3 γ) Log[a]) + 
        3 Λ Log[a]) (-((-2 + 3 γ) Log[a]) + 
         3 Λ Log[a])) ∈ Reals && 
   a^(1 + 3 γ + 
      3 Λ) (-2 + 3 γ - 3 Λ) Log[
      a] != 0 && ((0 < a < 1 && 1 < γ < 2 && 
       0 < Λ < 1/3 (-2 + 3 γ) && 
       b > (E^((-2 + 3 γ) Log[a] - 
          3 Λ Log[a]) (-2 Log[a] + 
           3 γ Log[a]))/(-((-2 + 3 γ) Log[a]) + 
         3 Λ Log[a])) || (a > 1 && 1 < γ < 2 && 
       0 < Λ < 1/3 (-2 + 3 γ) && 
       b > (E^((-2 + 3 γ) Log[a] - 
          3 Λ Log[a]) (-2 Log[a] + 
           3 γ Log[a]))/(-((-2 + 3 γ) Log[a]) + 
         3 Λ Log[a])))) || (a == 1 && 
   1 < γ < 2 && 0 < Λ < 1/3 (-2 + 3 γ) &&
    b > (2 - 3 γ)/(-2 + 3 γ - 3 Λ))
```

Comment: And `FillSimlify[%]` results in `0 < \[CapitalLambda] < -(2/3) + \[Gamma] && 
 1 < \[Gamma] < 
  2 && (((Log[a] | 
        a^(2 - 3 \[Gamma] + 3 \[CapitalLambda]) Log[a]) \[Element] 
      Reals && 
     b > (a^(-2 + 3 \[Gamma] - 
        3 \[CapitalLambda]) (2 - 3 \[Gamma]))/(-2 + 3 \[Gamma] - 
       3 \[CapitalLambda]) && (0 < a < 1 || a > 1) && 
     a^(1 + \[Gamma] + \[CapitalLambda]) (-2 + 3 \[Gamma] - 
         3 \[CapitalLambda]) Log[a] != 0) || a == 1)`.

Comment: Additional `Reduce[(-2/3 + \[Gamma])/a^2 + 
    a^(-3*\[Gamma] + 3*\[CapitalLambda])*(-2/
        3 + \[Gamma] - \[CapitalLambda])*b < 
   0 && -2/3 + \[Gamma] - \[CapitalLambda] < 0 && 
  1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && \[CapitalLambda] > 0 && a > 0, b, Reals]`  should be considered as part of the solution!

Comment: @ULrichNeumann: Can you present a real solution of the original system which is not a real solution of `(-2/3 + \[Gamma])/a^2 + a^(-3*\[Gamma] + 3*\[CapitalLambda])*(-2/ 3 + \[Gamma] -
 \[CapitalLambda])*b > 0 && -2/3 + \[Gamma] - \[CapitalLambda] > 0 && 
 1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && \[CapitalLambda] > 0 && a > 0`in orger to ground your claim?  Did you pay your attention to "Since `Sqrt` over the reals takes only non-negative values"? TIA

Comment: If both radicants are negative the condition is fullfilled too! Not more.

Comment: @ULrichNeumann:  What do you mean by "both radicants"? Where are these in `Sqrt[(-2/3 + \[Gamma])/((-2/3 + \[Gamma] - \[CapitalLambda]) a^2) + a^(-3 \[Gamma] + 3 \[CapitalLambda]) b] > 0 && 1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && \[CapitalLambda] > 0 && a > 0`? I see only one `Sqrt` there.`

Comment: I initially started with $\frac{\sqrt{b \left(g-l-\frac{2}{3}\right) a^{3 l-3
   g}+\frac{g-\frac{2}{3}}{a^2}}}{\sqrt{g-l-\frac{2}{3}}}$ but the expression seems to be modified?

Comment: @ULrichNeumann: Even in this case both square roots over the reals  are positive so your "If both radicants are negative the condition is fullfilled too! " is meaningless: `Reduce[Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[y] > 0, {x, y}, Reals]` outputs `x > 0 && y > 0`.

Comment: What about `Reduce[p/q > 0]  (*(q < 0 && p < 0) || (q > 0 && p > 0)*)`  ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann:  Sorry, how is it related to the question and the answer?

Comment: @MarcoB: Thank you for your edit.

Comment: @user64494 ,     Define `f = (Sqrt[(-2/
           3 + \[Gamma])/((-2/3 + \[Gamma] - \[CapitalLambda]) a^2) + 
       a^(-3 \[Gamma] + 3 \[CapitalLambda]) b] > 0 && 
    1 < \[Gamma] < 2 && \[CapitalLambda] > 0 && a > 0 && 
    b \[Element] Reals) /. Sqrt[aa__] -> Identity[aa] ` and your solution `g` . FindInstance shows, the result `g ` is wrong.  `{gfi = FindInstance[g, {a, b, \[Gamma], \[CapitalLambda]}, 4, 
   RandomSeed -> 1], f /. gfi} `  yields also complex b, means False.

Comment: @Akku14: By default `FindInstance` finds complex values. Try `FindInstance[g, {a, b, \[Gamma], \[CapitalLambda]}, Reals, 4`.

Comment: @user64494 , your solutions g should according to definition in Reduce restrict b to real solutions, but does not. I didn't test it, but i think, the equivalent simplification to the system, you made, does not hold for all parameter values.

Comment: @Akku14: You wrote "I didn't test it, but i think, the equivalent simplification to the system, you made, does not hold for all parameter values."  I prefer arguments over emotional and ungrounded words.

Comment: @user64494  The argument is, as i wrote, that FindInstance gives complex values for b, but it should give only real, since you got it with `Reduce[
  (-2/3 + γ)/a^2 + a^(-3*γ + 3*Λ)*(-2/ 3 + γ - Λ)*b > 0 &&
    -2/3 + γ - Λ > 0 && 
      1 < γ < 2 && Λ > 0 && a > 0, b, Reals] ` l. If you don't want to answer to that fact, then save your comments.